# How can you identify the Organization that sent an email?

Tags: email, org

In the `finish` method for a batch job it is common to send an email with code like:

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   // Get the ID of the AsyncApexJob representing this batch job
   // from Database.BatchableContext.
   // Query the AsyncApexJob object to retrieve the current job's information.
   AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
      TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
      FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =
      :BC.getJobId()];
   // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter notifying of job completion.
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
   mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
   mail.setSubject('Apex Sharing Recalculation ' + a.Status);
   mail.setPlainTextBody
   ('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
   ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
   Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

Source - [Using Database.BatchableContext](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm#database_batchable_context_interface).

**When the email from Messaging.sendEmail arrives, how can the Org that sent it be identified?**

Note that the question isn't specifically about batch jobs, they are just a common example of where the email would be sent (perhaps on a regular schedule) and the originating Org might be difficult to identify. In the above example it would be easy enough to append `UserInfo.getOrganizationId()` to the message body.

Answer (score 1):

Reid Carlberg [found a solution](https://twitter.com/ReidCarlberg/status/531939316906213377/photo/1) where the originating Org Id appears in the SMTP email header `X-SFDC-LK`. There is also `X-SFDC-User` with the senders User ID.

[image: X-SFDX-X SMTP Header]

See also:

- Knowledge Article Number: 000188046 - [What is the X-SFDC-ORGTYPE field in the email header?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000188046&language=en_US)