# How to locate a sandbox from an org id?

Tags: sandbox

I just got an inactive sandbox notification from Salesforce.  There's just one problem.  The org id listed in the email is not one of those that shows on the list of sandboxes connected with our production db.  That probably means it is something left over from a class or hands-on session. Is there a way to be sure?

I tried going to "test.salesforce.com" and doing the forgotten password option.  I haven't got the email yet (not in spam either).  This probably means I've forgotten the suffix I used to make my email address into my username for the db.

Comment: I got that email as well, but I don't think it's right - I only recently logged in to them to change my password...

Comment: A couple of potentially useful questions: [How to identify an Org from the Org ID](http://t.co/TKvavzuZ10) and [How can you identify the Organization that sent an email?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/55726/102)